# If you log out of Apple ID 1 onto Apple ID 2, will Apple ID 1's money disappear?

Tags: apple-id, ipad

I wish to log out of my dad's Apple ID on my iPad, as I have to join in an iTunes U discussion and the name is displayed as my dad's. There is a lot of money on my dad's Apple ID, and I'm not sure whether the money will still be on that Apple ID if I log out of it. So my question is this: If I log out of my dad's Apple ID and onto mine then will the money disappear? Also next time I log back onto my dad's Apple ID, will the money be there?

Comment: The money stays with the account.

Answer (score 2):

All account information is stored online, including account balances. Whether or not you are logged in to that account or another account on the iPad doesn't matter, as long as you don't make any purchases on his account.